# OpponentColorDescriptorExtractor opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to have the descriptor for keypoints with color information. so, i want to use "OpponentColorDescriptorExtractor" as mentioned here:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_extractors.html#opponentcolordescriptorextractor

I am using the following code but i am getting an error:

The following code is working:

```
SiftDescriptorExtractor detector;   
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> oppDescExtractor;

OpponentColorDescriptorExtractor opponentDescExtractor(oppDescExtractor);
```

The error is:

***OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!descriptorExtractor.empty()) in OpponentColorDescriptorExtractor,***

**So, how should i declare  "OpponentColorDescriptorExtractor" ?**

Answer (score 0):

`cv::Ptr` is a (smart) pointer only. Do what it says and create one :

```
cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> oppDescExtractor= new cv::SiftDescriptorExtractor;
cv::OpponentColorDescriptorExtractor opponentDescExtractor(oppDescExtractor);
```